# Click Font Awesome icon within Handlebar template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm having some trouble triggering popover when clicking a Font Awesome icon which is created dynamically.

index.ejs

```
<!-- Template for Snazzy Window -->
<script id="marker-content-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="custom-img" style="background-image: url({{{bgImg}}})"></div>
    <section class="custom-content">
        <h1 class="custom-header">
            {{title}} <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"></i>
            <small>{{governance}}</small>
        </h1>
        <div class="custom-body">{{{body}}}</div>
    </section>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#marker-content-template').html());
  });
</script>
```

I've tried various ways including

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa', function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
});
```

This doesn't work, and now I'm thinking does it have something to do with the Handlebar template?

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

As you run the

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa', function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
});
```

, handlebar created the element but hasn't added it to the DOM.

So in your code

```
// 1. Create the element from template with handlebar
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#marker-content-template').html()); 
// 2. Add the element to the DOM
document.getElementById('#yourTargetContainerId').innerHTML = template;
// 3. add the eventlistener to the elements
$(document).on('click', '.fa', function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, not the exact answer for my needs, but it made me realise what i needed to do and that was to call the popover in a callback, which was not clear in the question i know. Have marked as the answer though as this does work, thanks for the help :-)